# "String" and "int" type dictionary compare with "Unicode" type dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have three text files.
The one (zoo.txt) looks like this:

```
{'cow':'113', 'cat':'50', 'dog':'100', 'IDnumber':'113.1.22', 'type':'3'}
```

And it reads by json function:

```
file_open = open('zoo.txt', 'r')
zoo_animal = file_open.read()
zoo_animal = json.loads(zoo_animal)
```

And after the function, the output like this:

```
{u'cow':u'113', u'cat':u'50', u'dog':u'100', u'IDnumber':u'113.1.22', u'type':u'3'}
```

The other one is in_range.txt, it means the value of key in zoo.txt must match in this standard range.
The in_range.txt looks like:

```
cow 1 150
cat 0 25
dog 0 50
```

And it reads by with function:

```
with open('in_range.txt', 'r') as g:
for line in g:
    spliteLineR=line.split()
    in_range[str(spliteLineR[0])]=[int(spliteLineR[1]),int(spliteLineR[2])]
```

The output is:

```
{'cow':[1,150], 'cat':[0,25], 'dog':[0,50]}
```

The third text file is single_value.txt, it means the value of key in zoo.txt must equal to standard value.

The single_value.txt looks like:

```
IDnumber 1.8.70
type 1
```

And also it reads by with function:

```
with open('single_value.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        spliteLineS=line.split()
        single_value[str(spliteLineS[0])]=str(spliteLineS[1])
```

The output is:

```
{'IDnumber':'1.8.70', 'type':'1'}
```

My question is:

1. Do I need to transfer all type(str, int and unicode) to unicode or str then compare? because I use mathematical operators(<, ==, >) to compare directly, it can not get right answer.
2. If I need to transfer the type, how to do it?

Please give me a hand~ thank you very much~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to convert the ASCII strings to Unicode or vice versa, because ASCII is a subset of Unicode, so they behave sensibly when you do equality tests, eg

```
print('cow' == u'cow')
```

**output**

```
True
```

That code will work correctly in Python 2 or Python 3.

However, you *do* have to convert those numeric strings to a numeric type to perform numeric comparisons. Here's a short demo.

```
from __future__ import print_function

zoo_animal = {
    u'cow':u'113', u'cat':u'50', u'dog':u'100',
    u'IDnumber':u'113.1.22', u'type':u'3',
}
in_range = {'cow':[1, 150], 'cat':[0, 25], 'dog':[0, 50]}

for key in zoo_animal:
    if key in in_range:
        lo, hi = in_range[key]
        val = int(zoo_animal[key])
        print(key, val, lo <= val <= hi)
```

**output**

```
cow 113 True
cat 50 False
dog 100 False
```

Once again, that code works on both Python 2 and Python 3.